# How to Consume an API in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: json, api, jwt, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to consume an API in my MVC project. the actions in API are secured, So you need to access a token (JWT) to consume it. I face an error every time I try to deserialize the response into the model (Player). It says `*Could not cast or convert from System.String to MyMVC.Models.Player*`
When I run a debugger, the piece of code including deserialization is in red in the internal server error page.
Here is the action in API

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult<List<Player>> GetAllPlayers()
        {
            var players = _applicationDbContext.Players.OrderBy(p => p.Name).Select(p=> p.Name).ToList();
            return Ok(players);
        }
```

This is the action in the MVC project

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetPlayers()
        {
            var token = HttpContext.Session.GetString("Token");
            List<Player> players = new List<Player>();
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://localhost:53217/api/player");
            var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
            if(response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                var strResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                players = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Player>>(strResponse);

            }
            return View(players);

        }
```

Comment: First check what the API returns. I feel like it’s not returning what you expect it to

Comment: on running a debugger, the value of strResponse equals the name of all players. It worked fine on Postman when I tested the API. The problem appears while consuming the API on MVC

Comment: ""http://localhost:53217/api/player""  Please check your url.

Comment: @ahamadzooghi So if it’s only names (as in strings), how would they be able to be handled as objects?

Comment: Thanks to @SamiKuhmonen. I found the problem! The return value on API is of string, So there's no need to deserialize it, Because it's not an object! I deleted Select(p=>p.Name) so it worked! But I was wondering if I can still return the names by this code? I want to return just Name and Id of each player

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sami Kuhmonen 's comment is right.

```
 var players = _applicationDbContext.Players.OrderBy(p => p.Name).Select(p=> p.Name).ToList();
```

From here we can get name list not player list.

Name list contain string name. Player list contain object player1 {name="xx",age="xx"}

But

```
List<Player> players = new List<Player>();
var strResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
players = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Player>>(strResponse);
```

here  we need player list contain object players .

You can use below code in your API to get the playerlist.

```
var players = _applicationDbContext.Players.ToList();
```

[image]

I reproduce your problem. Then I use that method to solve it.

[image]

**Update**

Create a new class User contain the property that you want.

```
public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Then use the below code

```
var players = _applicationDbContext.Players.Select (P=>new User { Name=P.Name, Id=P.Id} ).ToList();
```

In mvc change `List<Player> players = new List<Player>();` to
`List<User> players = new List<User>();`

Result:

[image]

Comment: @ahamadzooghi Please see my update.